# How to prove that these integrals are the same with a Fourier transform?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fourier-transform, yang-mills, propagator

In the paper [BMN Correlators and Operator Mixing in $\mathcal{N}$=4 Super Yang-Mills Theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0208178), they claim in Appendix $A.2$ (p.26, eq. $(A.7)$) that the following relation holds:

$$F_{12,34} = \frac{(\partial_1 - \partial_2)\cdot(\partial_3 - \partial_4) H_{12,34}}{I_{12}I_{34}} \overset{!}{=} \frac{X_{1234}}{I_{13}I_{24}} - \frac{X_{1234}}{I_{14}I_{23}} + G_{1,34} - G_{2,34} + G_{3,12} - G_{4,12} \tag{1}$$

with

$$\begin{align} &I_{12} = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^2(x_1-x_2)^2} \tag{2}\\ &Y_{123} = \int d^4w I_{1w} I_{2w} I_{3w} \tag{3} \\ &X_{1234} = \int d^4w I_{1w} I_{2w} I_{3w} I_{4w} \tag{4} \\ &H_{12,34} = \int d^4 u\ d^4v\ I_{1u} I_{2u} I_{3v} I_{4v} I_{uv} \tag{5} \\ &G_{1,34} = \frac{Y_{134}}{I_{14}} - \frac{Y_{134}}{I_{13}} \tag{6} \end{align}$$

I would like to prove the relation given in $(1)$. To support this claim, the authors say

> The equality of the two expressions can be shown by transforming them
>   to momentum space and writing the inverse propagators as derivatives
>   on the momenta, i.e. $1/I_{12} = (2\pi)^2 (x_1-x_2)^2 =
>  -(2\pi)^2(\partial_{p_1} - \partial_{p_2})^2$.

I could not manage to prove the relation so far. Any suggestion?

**Edit**: here is what I have tried. I attempted to derive the Fourier transform of $F_{12,34}$:

$$\tilde{F}_{12,34} = \int d^4 x_{1234} e^{-i \Sigma p \cdot x} x_{12}^2 x_{34}^2 \left(\partial_1 - \partial_2 \right) \cdot \left(\partial_1 - \partial_2 \right) \int d^4 u\ d^4 v \frac{1}{x_{1u}^2x_{2u}^2x_{3v}^2x_{4v}^2x_{uv}^2} \tag{7}$$

with $d^4 x_{1234} := d^4 x_1 d^4 x_2 d^4 x_3 d^4 x_4$ and with

$$\int d^4 u\ d^4 v \frac{1}{x_{1u}^2x_{2u}^2x_{3v}^2x_{4v}^2x_{uv}^2} = \int d^4 k_{12345}\int d^4 u\ d^4 v \frac{1}{k_1^2 k_2^2 k_3^2 k_4^2 k_5^2} e^{i \left\lbrace k_1 \cdot x_{1u} +k_2 \cdot x_{2u} +k_3 \cdot x_{3v} +k_4 \cdot x_{4v} +k_1 \cdot x_{uv} \right\rbrace} \tag{8}$$

One can already spot with naked eye the problem that I face: there are five integrals over momentum space and six integrals over position space, which means that, once I perform all the integrals over position space, the resulting delta functions will kill all the integrals over $k_i$ and even leave one extra delta function, which I don't know what to do with (I guess this is just conservation of external momentum though). This is indeed what happens when I do the computation:

$$\tag{9} \tilde{F}_{12,34} = \left( \partial_{p_1} - \partial_{p_2} \right)^2 \left( \partial_{p_3} - \partial_{p_4} \right)^2 \frac{(p_1 - p_2) \cdot (p_1 + p_2)}{p_1^2 p_2^2 p_3^2 p_4^2 (p_1 + p_2)^2} \delta^{(4)}(p_1 + p_2 - p_3 -p_4)$$

Moreover, the derivatives apply on the delta function as well, so I cannot really perform them as far as I can see. This is where I am stuck, still pretty far from the relation given in $(1)$ unfortunately.

Comment: It would help if you provide some of your previous attempts.  For example are you FT in space and time dimensions uniformly?

Comment: @ggcg Yes, if by that you mean that I treat space and time in the same way. This is Euclidean space by the way. Regarding the attempts, well I am stuck quite early on, because I am not sure if I should transform $F_{12,34}$ or $H_{12,34}$ in the first place.

Comment: @ggcg I have added what I have tried. Maybe it helps indeed to see where I am confused.

Comment: Okay I managed to show it, it was insane and a full proof certainly does not belong here (you can contact me if somebody is interested though). Sorry for the question, I did not realize at first how intricate this identity was.

Comment: I'm glad you solved it.  Sorry, but I didn't follow up.  You should answer your question and claim the bounty.

Comment: @ggcg I would love to do so, but the proof is extremely involved. Maybe I can roughly sketch it though.

Comment: You could either use Mathjax or write it out on paper and upload a photo.  If it's worth your time.

Comment: @ggcg Well, the problem is that it is really, really long and intricate. But I will write a sketch of the proof as soon as I can.